# suma de elementos en posición par oprima en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, python-2.7, ipython

Hola Buenas tardes disculpen alguien sabe como sumar los elementos que están en una posición par o prima dentro de un arreglo definido por el usuario en Python?

Comment: Saludos Cynthya, edita tu pregunta agregando el código que has intentado mostrando el error o la parte donde tienes dificultad. Bienvenida a SOes.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con posición prima si puedo preguntar?

Comment: "par o prima" o quizistes decir "par o impar"?

Comment: El borito y Germán Martínez: los números primos no son divisibles entre 2, por ejemplo si el programa que estoy ejecutando está en forma de lista[] es para que el usuario agregue la lista yo no se que elementos contiene dicha lista pero el programa sabe en que posición esta cada elemento de la lista si agrego 1 a la posición el programa detectará el primer número como el elemento en la posición 1 y será par y el siguiente estará en posición 2 por lo que estará en la posición par y el siguiente en posición 3 por lo que será primo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que vos queres realizar se puede hacer de varias maneras. Te voy a exponer una que si bien no es optima, es para mí la mas simple: es usando slicing ,dado que este es un concepto interesante pero muy abarcativo no creo conveniente hablar de él acá, pero sin dudas hay mucho contenido en la web. Podríamos entenderlo (muy por arriba) como un for-loop sobre la lista: 
Entonces dada una lista con diez elementos:

`e = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Sumar solo los de in indice pares (teniendo en cuenta que el primer elemento es 0 y entra dentro de la convención de los numero pares) se resolvería con la función sum():
`resultado = sum(e[::2])`

Y para sumar los indices impares sería comenzando desde el primer elemento:
`resultado = sum(e[1::2])`

En cuanto a los indices equivalentes a números primos no existe una forma general, ya que teoricamente no existe un calculo exacto para hallar números primos, pero en caso de que consideremos un limite determinado (por ejemplo los primos menores  a 11) podemos almacenarlo en variable y luego usarlo como filtro para crear una lista solo con esos elementos:

```
e = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
primos = [2,3,5,7]
resultado = [x for x in e if e.index(x) in primos]
```

Se pueden generar números primos con ciertas librerias (por ejemplo: pyprimes) pero obviamente cabe aclarar que cada una tiene sus ventajas/desventajas.
Espero que ta haya sido de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias Alexis por tomar tu tiempo y responder voy a correrlo y te comento.